# How to make SQLAlchemy issue additional SQL after flushing the current session?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, events, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some SQL that I'd like SQLAlchemy to issue after it flushes the *current* session.

So I'm trying to write a Python function that will do the following "at the end of this specific SQLAlchemy session, 1) flush the session, 2) then send this extra SQL to the database as well, 3) then finally commit the session", but only if I call it within that particular session.

I don't want it on all sessions globally, so if I didn't call the function within this session, then don't execute the SQL.

I know SQLAlchemy has a built-in events system, and I played around with it, but I can't figure out how to register an event listener for only the current session, and not all sessions globally. I read the docs, but I'm still not getting it.

I am aware of database triggers, but they won't work for this particular scenario.

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, which uses scoped sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it does not work for you. Sample code below runs as expected:

```
class Stuff(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stuff'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(session, 'after_flush')
def _handle_event(session, context):
    print('>> --- after_flush started ---')
    rows = session.execute("SELECT 1 AS XXX").fetchall()
    print(rows)
    print('>> --- after_flush finished ---')

# create test data
s1 = Stuff(name='uno')
session.add(s1)
print('--- before calling commit ---')
session.commit()
print('--- after  calling commit ---')
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't fully clear in my question. This registers the function as a listener on **every** session's flush, but I want the function to **only** start listening for the event if I call the function at some point within the code for that particular session. I'll expand that part of the question

Comment: No, it is not on every session, it is for a particular `Session` instance (in the code above called `session`). And you can register this event handler in the function you want to call. you could also de-register it on commit event hook or another helper function call.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was hitting a bug in Flask-SQLAlchemy: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/364 
Thanks for following up--it worked as soon as I switched to pip installing from master instead of Pypi.

Comment: I think you still might have an issue when re-using this instance of session afterwards, because the event still be registered. ideally, there would be `one-time` event model. But I do not think it is possible, and de-registering from event during the event handling will result in an error. So you either should not re-use the session, or de-register event handle explicitely.

Comment: Yeah, your answer actually helped me understand how events are used a lot better--basically the docs started to make sense. From there, I realized the better solution was to pick a different event where I do want it to trigger every time... again, thanks for your example, it was what I needed once I also figured out the session issue.